# Django anymail links in emails are changed and don't work

Tags: python, django, mailgun, sparkpost

I'm trying to do something which I would have thought should be very simple but appears to be very complicated.

I'm using Django Anymail, with SparkPost as ESP. I want to include a link back to my site in the email, something like `<a href="www.example.com>click here</a>`.

However, no matter what I do, that link gets changed to something like:
`http://go.sparkpostmail1.com/f/a/Vju1M3X6TVz79ONI6TywgA~~/AAOsuQA~/RgRdt_u-...`

Then, when I click on the link I just get a `This site can’t be reached`. I've disabled click and open tracking, and I've tried sending the email both as content generated in Django and as a SparkPost template, and I've even tried switching ESP to Mailgun and I get the same results.

Here's my Anymail config:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "anymail.backends.sparkpost.EmailBackend"

ANYMAIL = {

    "SPARKPOST_API_KEY": "MY_KEY",
    "SPARKPOST_API_URL": "https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1",
    'SPARKPOST_SENDER_DOMAIN': "mail.mysite.com",

    "SEND_DEFAULTS": {
        "track_clicks": False,
        "track_opens": False,
    },
}
```

Here's my message sending function:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from smtplib import SMTPException

def send_welcome_email( address ):
  subject, from_email = 'Hello! Thank you for your interest in Discover three.js', 'Discover three.js <welcome@mail.discoverthreejs.com>'

  html_content = '<a href="www.example.com">click here</a>'
  message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, 'Hello!', from_email, [address])
  message.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

  # alternatively, use sparkpost template
  #message.template_id = 'welcome'

  # Tried both of these settings to no avail
  #message.track_clicks = False
  #message.click_tracking= False

  try:
    message.send()
  except SMTPException as e:
    print('There was an error sending an email: ', e)
```

I've tried this both with and without click and open tracking, it makes no difference.

Comment: Where did you did find those options for disabling trackings? Unless anymail does something different, those are wrong. Correct values are `open_tracking`, `click_tracking`.

Comment: They are mentioned several times in the anymail docs. For example, in the main github repo they use `msg.track_clicks = True`.  In any case, I've tried changing it to your suggestions and it makes no difference. I've edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: The sparkpost official python app also uses `track_clicks` and `track_opens`, it seems like these are probably correct.

Comment: i see, it it could be anymail that translates it to esp specific settings. i'm not much familiar with anymail. however, you can globally disable them from your SparkPost account https://app.sparkpost.com/account/smtp (check Engagement Setting)

Comment: yes, you're right. lib translates to actual flags https://github.com/SparkPost/python-sparkpost/blob/master/sparkpost/transmissions.py#L40-L41

Comment: **you can globally disable them from your SparkPost account**. 

This setting is disabled by default and I never changed it so it has been disabled the entire time I've been debugging this. Anymail must be overriding it in some way.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by switching from Anymail to the official Sparkpost python app.

Installations instructions for Django are [here](https://python-sparkpost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and details for disabling click tracking are [here](https://python-sparkpost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django/backend.html).

The API for the Sparkpost python app is almost identical to the the Anymail API, and since disabling click tracking for this worked immediately, while I've spent a long time trying to get it to work with Anymail over two different ESPs, I can only conclude that this is probably an Anymail bug.

Answer (score 0):

For the same problem with sendgrid, this anymail configuration in your `settings.py` will turn off click and open tracking.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'anymail.backends.sendgrid.EmailBackend'

ANYMAIL = {
    'SENDGRID_API_KEY': site_keys.send_grid,
    "SEND_DEFAULTS": {
        "track_clicks": False,
        "track_opens": False,
    },
}
```